# Run AWS Device Farm Built in Explorer test on a responsive web app

Tags: aws-device-farm

We are building a responsive Web App. As it is responsive it has no .apk and .ipa files.

Can I use the AWS Device Farm Built in Explorer tests for my responsive Web App?

If Yes, please let me know how to configure it thru AWS Device Farm

Thanks
qa

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. The built-in explorer tests do a depth first search of the views in an Android app. Because we don't have an app and we're testing a website 
, this option shouldn't be available to us.  We haft to choose from the appium java/python client whilst using Device Farm.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-overview.html

Hth

James

Comment: James,:   When you say we have to choose a appium java/python client whilst using Device Farm, does it mean I have to upload all my applium tests built for my web app and then run them on devices?

Comment: Yes, once you upload the test you can reuse them so you don't need to keep reuploading.